# Multiple origin when creating jwt token for Apple Maps?

Tags: javascript, jwt, apple-maps, mapkit-js

I'm following this guide from Apple to create a jwt token to use with their Apple Maps JS Kit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/creating_and_using_tokens_with_mapkit_js

It works, but how can I set multiple origins? I wan't it to allow `localhost`, `production-url` and `production-backend-url`. But it looks like it only accepts a string.

Currently I'm doing:

```
origin:
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:3000"
    : "https://production-url"
```

But how can it also allow the third domain?

Comment: Consider not using a ternary? Try using a function with a swtich statement, or a bunch of if statements which return a value?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about. I wan't to specify multiple origins. E.g. using an array or some other method.

Comment: Well, a ternary is what is limiting you to only two URLs? You could use an object `const domains = { development: urlA }; domains[process.env.NODE_ENV]`? --- It's good to show what you have already tried rather than asking for ideas on how to implement something.

Comment: Probably not that great question, I can see that it's difficult to figure out what I'm actually asking for. I figured it out, see answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for defining multiple origins is like this:

```
origin: "http://localhost:3000,https://first.domain,https://second.domain"
```

Figured this out by trial and error. Not documented anywhere I could find.